# Power series representation of $\ln(1+x)$?

Tags: calculus, logarithms, power-series, taylor-expansion

I am reading an example in which the author is finding the power series representation of $\ln(1+x)$. Here is the parts related to the question:

[image]
I think that I get everything except for one thing: Why do we need to find a *specific* constant $C$ and not just leave at as an arbitrary constant? And why do we find the specific constant we need by setting x=0 and solve the given equation?

Comment: Note that we have

$$\int_0^x \frac1{1+t}\,dt=\log(1+x)=\int_0^x \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1}t^{n-1}\,dx=\sum_{n=1}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{x^n}{n}$$

Comment: The logarithm is a function, meaning that it has a well defined value for a given $x$. You can't leave an undetermined constant in the definition !

Comment: The result allowing us to integrate a power series term-by-term specifically calls for a *definite* integral.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because it is *not* true that we have$$\log(1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^3}3-\frac{x^4}4+\cdots+C$$for an *arbitrary* constant $C$. Since, when $x=0$, the LHS is $0$ and RHS is $C$, $C=0$.

Comment: Ah okay, I see! But is that obvious? I mean it has not been explicitly stated anywhere - so how do someone like you arrive at that conclusion?

Comment: By replacing $x$ by a specific number for which both $\log(1+x)$ and $x-\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^3}3-\frac{x^4}4+\cdots$ are easy to compute.

Comment: But couldn't there is theory be another number than zero that would make it easy to compute while giving the wrong C? If not, why?

Comment: No, it is not possible. Because, if $C_1\neq C_2$, you have$$(\forall x\in\mathbb R):x-\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^3}3-\frac{x^4}4+\cdots+C_1=x-\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^3}3-\frac{x^4}4+\cdots+C_2.$$So, at most one of the functions$$x\mapsto x-\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^3}3-\frac{x^4}4+\cdots+C$$can possibly be equal to $\log(1+x)$.

Comment: Put another way, the function $\log(1 + x)$ has one derivative, $\frac{1}{1 + x}$, and that latter function has many antiderivatives, but only one of them is the function we started with.

Answer (score 0):

Since the original function is $\log (1+x)$ and for $x=0$ we have $\log (1+0)=0$ we need that also the series is zero for $x=0$.